# linear regression-slope

Tags: regression

Your friend in the U.S. gives you a simple regression fit for predicting house prices from square feet. The estimated intercept is -44850 and the estimated slope is 280.76. You believe that your housing market behaves very similarly, but houses are measured in square meters. To make predictions for inputs in square meters, what slope must you use? Hint: there are 0.092903 square meters in 1 square foot.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: (-44850+280.76) / 0.092903

Comment: Sq M ^ 2,

0.092903 ^ -44850     seems not getting it right

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same question. You have to divide by the unit you want.
So, your slope is based in USD/sq ft. And the same for the input (sq ft or $$ft^2$$).

One simple workaround is to divide both slope and input by  0.092903
( 1 $$ft^2 =  0.092903 m^2 $$)

There you are. You have converted sq ft to sq m for the input, and USD/sq ft to USD/sq m for the slope. If you need other currency (USD to CAD), the same thing for intercept and slope (USD/sq ft to CAD/sq ft)